# Increasing dataset gives "Fail to convert Numpy array to Tensor"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network and have data that contains samples with 10 000 features. A single sample is a 1-D array of size 10 000 and the output is a 1-D array of size 10 000. When I train my neural network on 10 samples it runs with no errors but when I increase it to 100 samples it returns

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)"
```

Why does the model fit fine with 10 samples but throws an error with 100 samples? Nothing in my code changes except the number of samples.

Comment: Sounds like the 100 sample case uses an array of arrays. While 100 samples of 10,000-element arrays is too much, you should show at least the relevant code. We could then point out where to test for specifics of your input data.

Comment: Usually this problem arises because one or more of the new samples does not have the same shape as the others.  What's the `shape` of this array of samples?  Object dtype suggests it's an array of arrays, 1d, (100,), not a 2d array (which would have a (100,10000) shape.